# background-color on dynamic display inline-block page

Tags: html, css

I was working on a page with dynamic width and have the following situation:
[image: element layout]
and here's a simple fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kk0s4dqc/2/

HTML:

```
<div class="header">header
</div>

<div class="outer">
<div class="background">    
    <div class="inner">element 1
    </div>
    <div class="inner">element 2
    </div>
    <div class="inner">element 3
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header{width:500px; height:50px; margin: 0 auto; background:yellow;}

.outer{width:100%; text-align:center;}
.background{display:inline-block; background:red}
.inner{width:200px; height: 40px; background:blue; display:inline-block; margin:3px}
```

as you can see everything works as intended as long as the 3 inner elements are on the same line (shrink window a little), but since the page is dynamic I don't know the width of the inner elements or the screen width and the elements need to be aligned at the center as shown.

The goal is to display as many elements per line as there fit on the scrren width and then going into the next line, but the backgound should only be around the inner divs, not the whole screen. Also the background div needs to be able to have a background image and drop a shadow.

I guess it cannot be solved with floats and clears, since I don't know how many elements there will be per line.

Anyone has a more or less crossbrowser (IE8+ I guess), non-javascript solution? Help is much appreciated.

**edit**
a pseudo element doesn't seem to be the solution, but its getting closer (as seen here http://jsfiddle.net/dm8g196g/ the background works well, but the shadow fails since it doesn't drop from the gaps between the elements.

**edit2**
If anyone finds a solution (posibly without pseudo-elements) feel free to post it. An acceptable alternative solution for me is calculating the max-width of the background div with calc() and do some fallback with static values.

Comment: Maybe `outline: 5px solid red;`? http://jsfiddle.net/kk0s4dqc/3/

Comment: On the actual page I need a complex background (with a bcg image) and it also needs to be able to drop a shadow. A div wrapping the inner elements seems like the only way to achieve this.

Comment: Then the `:before` pseudoelement? http://jsfiddle.net/kk0s4dqc/4/

Comment: that definitely looks better, but it would also drop shadow between the elements (not just the bottom and the sides) of the background div.

Comment: This is my best, but it has too much hard-coded sizes: http://jsfiddle.net/kk0s4dqc/6/

Comment: What about some extra markup? http://jsfiddle.net/kk0s4dqc/11/

Comment: They need to stack in rows only, as much of them as there fit in one line should be placed in one line, just like in the "edit" fiddle. The only issue is the shadow not being consistent on the bottom side. I don't want it to stack into some pyramid shape, but still thanks for the help.

Comment: That was an artificial pyramid. Shadows seem okay at me in mac firefox+safari. http://jsfiddle.net/kk0s4dqc/12/

Comment: Its working well except that I don't need a border radius on the background, which then sadly looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/3xsmmnL7/ if the shadow were straight the problem would be solved.

Comment: So why not remove the border radius?Confused. :-/

Comment: sorry for being so specific, but the elements have rounded borders, but the background div should not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `media="condition for media"`

for eg

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text\css" href="linkToYourCSS.css" media="screen and (min-width:1000px)">
```

You can replace min-width with height, max-width etc & declare the specified CSS there. 
Read more at http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_media.asp

Or else you can define height, width in %